# Google Chrome Launcher Not Installed on Unity Bar

Tags: icons, google-chrome

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 today. I expected the Google Chrome Browser to be part of the install. When I didn't see the icon I went to the Ubuntu software web page and downloaded and installed the browser. I was informed that it had installed successfully. Still no icon. I use g.mail so the Chrome Browser is important to me.

Comment: Google Chrome has never been included by default. It's also not available in the repositories, maybe you mean Chromium?.

Comment: @user167537 where are you looking for the browser icon?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome is not included in the Ubuntu Repositories.

The closest equivalent is `chromium-browser`, which can be installed easily using the software center, if it is not yet installed on your system.

---

However, this will NOT install a launcher to the Unity bar for that program, because only Firefox is included "by default" in Ubuntu.

You need to lock alternate browsers to there manually.

First, run the web browser by going to the dash (first button on Unity), and type in the browser name.

Second, click the icon for the browser.

Third, after the browser opens, right-click the new icon on the unity bar, and choose "Lock to Launcher"

Boom, new launcher for that browser.

Comment: I looked for the browser icon just above the waste basket on the left hand side of the start page. the Firefox icon is several icons above it.

Comment: @user167537 see my edit please.